# Bad ground??? Service panel updated!! Dim lights

Tags: wiring

I'm having a issue,when I open tmy fridge it's dim,when I open my oven the clock goes dim,had this issue before but it was the ground bar and wire, new service panel but it's still happening,I've checked all my grounds everything is tight,I'm at a standstill

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You should talk to your installer; there's no way we could diagnose the problem from here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible Neutral Out

Get a multimeter. Check voltage at several different receptacles - all *should* read about the same ~ 120V. If you have a 240V receptacle - e.g., electric dryer - check from each hot to neutral and between hots - you should get ~ 120V for each hot to neutral and ~ 240V between hots.

If you get find that some receptacles are way above 120V and some receptacles below 120V, and particularly if you find that a 240V receptacle has something other than 1/2 the voltage on each individual hot-to-neutral (e.g., 240V hot-to-hot but 130V on one hot-to-neutral and 110V on the other hot-to-neutral), and also if the voltage changes significantly when you turn various appliances on and off, then you very likely have a **LOST NEUTRAL**. That is a dangerous situation and is normally a **CALL THE POWER COMPANY IMMEDIATELY** situation because most of the time it is on their side of the meter.

Another possibility is a one leg of your service is out. Less likely based on your description as typically then certain things would start/stop working when a 240V appliance (e.g., dryer, oven, air conditioner, water heater) is turned on/off. But that is also a **CALL THE POWER COMPANY** situation.

That being said, anything *can* happen and these same problems (as well as many others) can be the result of circuit breaker panel problems. But I'd get a multimeter and if you find high/low then definitely call the electric company.

Answer (score 1):

### Grounds don't cause dim lights

Grounds are **not** part of the normal flow of current, and it is unlikely to be a player in a "dim lights" scenario.

### Hot or neutral

Normally, lighting loads flow from one of the hot wires to neutral.  If either the hot wire or the neutral has a problem, dimming can occur.  Note that problems tend to happen at wire terminations - switches, outlets, service panel, meter, etc.

- The hot wire may be *partially* failing.  If so, dimming can only mean an **arcing fault** is occurring somewhere.  This is making a lot of heat. This scenario is a firestarter.
- The neutral wire may be failing partially *or entirely*.  A total failure is not a firestarter (directly) but will cause weird voltages on the hot circuits. One phase may be 90 volts while the other one is 150 volts. *This voltage will change as you add and remove load*.

If you see the same kind of voltage changes on all circuits and at the top of your panel, far and away the most likely cause is the outdoor wiring. This, being the power company's wiring, is their responsibility.

### The **grounding electrode system** could be an indicator, though

If messing with the grounding electrodes changes the symptom somewhat, *that isn't the problem* but it does provide a valid hint.  This indicates a totally broken neutral wire. The system is *trying* to use ground as an alternative, but dirt is a rather bad conductor.   This is especially one where you need to call the power company and get it fixed.